# FFMPEG: Video has same Dimensions even after Crop

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG to do dynamic crop in a video.

The problem is, If I crop a 1920x1080 video to 100x100 am still getting a 1920x1080 video with only 100x100 part visible and other part tuned to green.

```
_flutterFFmpeg.execute('-y -i $input -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=$txtFile,crop" $output');
```

txtFile:

```
0 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 10, crop y 10;
1 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 10, crop y 10;
2 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 10, crop y 10;
3 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 10, crop y 10;
4 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 10, crop y 10;
5 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 10, crop y 10;
6 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 0, crop y 0;
7 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 0, crop y 0;
8 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 0, crop y 0;
9 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 0, crop y 0;
10 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 0, crop y 0;
11 crop w 100, crop h 100, crop x 0, crop y 0;
```

The output Video File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10mjY9toRoMmlvazD6m57gIiuJa8Sqjki/view?usp=sharing

As you see, the Output contains Green Sides for the first 5 seconds and the rest of the video is not cropped at all.

Answer (score 0):

Set initial crop to have the same `w` and `h` as set in `$txtFile` to avoid default values of `w=iw` and `h=ih` at beginning:

```
_flutterFFmpeg.execute('-y -i $input -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=$txtFile,crop=w=100:h=100" $output');
```